# Load multiple configmaps using fabric kubernetes-client in JAVA

Tags: java, kubernetes, fabric.io

I am getting an error when I try to load a configMap with multiple configurations(maps)

*Java code*

```
ConfigMap aConfigMap = client.configMaps()
            .load(Files.newInputStream(path.resolve("configmap.yaml")))
            .get();
```

*configmap.yaml*

```
 ---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: template-config
...
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: template-log-config
...
```

I read that this was solved in some other language while using loadAll() instead of load().

**Question:**

1. Any idea where can I log a bug to fabric.io kubernetes-client(java) to report this issue?
2. As I have to use multiple configmaps for now, any suggestions for workaround?

Thanks,

Swaraj

Comment: Seems like it is a known bug (Obviously fixed). https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client/issues/3648 
as a temp workaround, you can parse configmap but its native delimiter and load one by one